# Ubuntu 16.04 lts - network does not start on boot - bonding

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ethernet

Ubuntu 16.04 lts server with 4 nics bonded on IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation.

Upon reboot, the network service fails to load automatically and have to do a manual start using `sudo /etc/init.d/networking start`

All the interfaces including the bond have an auto load in the `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# The second network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# The third network interface
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# The forth network interface
auto eth3
iface eth3 inet manual
bond-master bond0


# The bond master network interface
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.201
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.254
        dns-nameservers xx.xx.xx.x xx.xx.xx.xx
        dns-search xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
        bond-mode 4
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-slaves all
        bond-primary eth1 eth2 eth3 eth0
```

This is supposed to start the network service upon reboot, but its not. What can I do to have the network start on boot?

**Edit 1**

[image]

**Edit 2**

Output of `dmesg | grep -i bond0`:

```
borgf003@CLD01:~$ dmesg | grep -i bond0
[   12.110687] bond0: Setting MII monitoring interval to 100
[   12.121534] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): bond0: link is not ready
[   12.191915] bond0: Adding slave eno2
[   12.348156] bond0: Enslaving eno2 as a backup interface with a down link
[   12.350247] bond0: Adding slave enp12s0f0
[   12.608573] bond0: Enslaving enp12s0f0 as a backup interface with a down link
[   12.608598] bond0: Adding slave enp12s0f1
[   12.856531] bond0: Enslaving enp12s0f1 as a backup interface with a down link
[   12.856552] bond0: Adding slave eno1
[   12.980244] bond0: Enslaving eno1 as a backup interface with a down link
[   13.980065] bond0: link status definitely up for interface eno2, 100 Mbps ful                                                                                                                                                             l duplex
[   13.980071] bond0: now running without any active interface!
[   13.980076] bond0: link status definitely up for interface enp12s0f0, 100 Mbp                                                                                                                                                             s full duplex
[   14.080093] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): bond0: link becomes ready
[   14.280062] bond0: link status definitely up for interface enp12s0f1, 100 Mbp                                                                                                                                                             s full duplex
[   14.680033] bond0: link status definitely up for interface eno1, 100 Mbps ful                                                                                                                                                             l duplex
[  194.727579] bond0: Removing slave enp12s0f1
[  194.727776] bond0: Releasing active interface enp12s0f1
[  195.010788] bond0: Removing slave eno2
[  195.010872] bond0: Releasing active interface eno2
[  195.010876] bond0: the permanent HWaddr of eno2 - 00:1a:a0:06:f1:dd - is stil                                                                                                                                                             l in use by bond0 - set the HWaddr of eno2 to a different address to avoid confl                                                                                                                                                             icts
[  195.010879] bond0: first active interface up!
[  195.207016] bond0: Removing slave enp12s0f0
[  195.207075] bond0: Releasing active interface enp12s0f0
[  195.207079] bond0: first active interface up!
[  195.278500] bond0: Removing slave eno1
[  195.278553] bond0: Removing an active aggregator
[  195.278556] bond0: Releasing active interface eno1
[  195.293395] bonding: bond0 is being deleted...
[  195.293460] bond0 (unregistering): Released all slaves
[  195.358558] bonding: bond0 is being created...
[  195.404957] bond0: Setting MII monitoring interval to 100
[  195.407792] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): bond0: link is not ready
[  195.462566] bond0: Adding slave eno1
[  195.584227] bond0: Enslaving eno1 as a backup interface with a down link
[  195.665846] bond0: Adding slave eno2
[  195.796166] bond0: Enslaving eno2 as a backup interface with a down link
[  195.864614] bond0: Adding slave enp12s0f0
[  196.104464] bond0: Enslaving enp12s0f0 as a backup interface with a down link
[  196.167753] bond0: Adding slave enp12s0f1
[  196.408475] bond0: Enslaving enp12s0f1 as a backup interface with a down link
[  197.204043] bond0: link status definitely up for interface eno1, 100 Mbps ful                                                                                                                                                             l duplex
[  197.204052] bond0: now running without any active interface!
[  197.204110] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): bond0: link becomes ready
[  197.504039] bond0: link status definitely up for interface eno2, 100 Mbps ful                                                                                                                                                             l duplex
[  197.504045] bond0: link status definitely up for interface enp12s0f0, 100 Mbp                                                                                                                                                             s full duplex
[  197.804037] bond0: link status definitely up for interface enp12s0f1, 100 Mbp                                                                                                                                                             s full duplex
[ 1048.788210] bond0: Removing slave enp12s0f1
[ 1048.788421] bond0: Releasing active interface enp12s0f1
[ 1048.996159] bond0: Removing slave enp12s0f0
[ 1048.996331] bond0: Releasing active interface enp12s0f0
[ 1049.200059] bond0: Removing slave eno2
[ 1049.200152] bond0: Releasing active interface eno2
[ 1049.366490] bond0: Removing slave eno1
[ 1049.366548] bond0: Removing an active aggregator
[ 1049.366551] bond0: Releasing active interface eno1
[ 1049.377410] bonding: bond0 is being deleted...
[ 1049.377479] bond0 (unregistering): Released all slaves
[ 1049.449847] bonding: bond0 is being created...
[ 1049.507089] bond0: Setting MII monitoring interval to 100
[ 1049.510405] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): bond0: link is not ready
[ 1049.554116] bond0: Adding slave eno1
[ 1049.657057] bond0: Enslaving eno1 as a backup interface with a down link
[ 1049.730913] bond0: Adding slave eno2
[ 1049.849103] bond0: Enslaving eno2 as a backup interface with a down link
[ 1049.914038] bond0: Adding slave enp12s0f0
[ 1050.160523] bond0: Enslaving enp12s0f0 as a backup interface with a down link
[ 1050.226176] bond0: Adding slave enp12s0f1
[ 1050.476519] bond0: Enslaving enp12s0f1 as a backup interface with a down link
[ 1051.312039] bond0: link status definitely up for interface eno1, 100 Mbps ful                                                                                                                                                             l duplex
[ 1051.312049] bond0: now running without any active interface!
[ 1051.312103] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): bond0: link becomes ready
[ 1051.612040] bond0: link status definitely up for interface eno2, 100 Mbps ful                                                                                                                                                             l duplex
[ 1051.612046] bond0: link status definitely up for interface enp12s0f0, 100 Mbp                                                                                                                                                             s full duplex
[ 1051.912060] bond0: link status definitely up for interface enp12s0f1, 100 Mbp                                                                                                                                                             s full duplex
borgf003@CLD01:~$
```

**Edit 3**

Checking bond0

```
borgf003@CLD01:~$ cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP rate: slow
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable

Slave Interface: eno1
MII Status: up
Speed: 100 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:1a:a0:06:f1:db
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: monitoring
Partner Churn State: monitoring
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0

Slave Interface: eno2
MII Status: up
Speed: 100 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:1a:a0:06:f1:dd
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: monitoring
Partner Churn State: monitoring
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0

Slave Interface: enp12s0f0
MII Status: up
Speed: 100 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:15:17:4a:94:26
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: monitoring
Partner Churn State: monitoring
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0

Slave Interface: enp12s0f1
MII Status: up
Speed: 100 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:15:17:4a:94:27
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: monitoring
Partner Churn State: monitoring
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0
borgf003@CLD01:~$
```

The link is slow due to the old Cisco Catalyst Switch in place.

**Edit 4**

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor prese
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2016-12-19 16:11:01 CET; 4min 10s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 3783 ExecStop=/sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment (code=exited, status
  Process: 3933 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=
  Process: 3927 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [
 Main PID: 3933 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/networking.service

Dec 19 16:11:00 CLD01 systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Dec 19 16:11:00 CLD01 ifup[3933]: Waiting for bond master bond0 to be ready
Dec 19 16:11:01 CLD01 systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
```

The bond seems to be initiating before the interfaces are raised

**Edit 5**

Problem was solved see the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/862630/629015)

Comment: see my updated answer.

Comment: are you using a router ?

Comment: updated answer look at _step 7_ Got that from [ServerVault](http://serverfault.com/questions/776057/802-3ad-bonding-configuration-file-on-an-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server). There seem to be a slight  difference in the way bonding is done on Ubuntu Xenial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved - Ubuntu 16.04 lts bonding with IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic Link Aggregation

**Situation**

Dell PowerEdge 2950 running NextCloud Server over Ubuntu 16.04 lts with unstable bonded 802.3ad dynamic link aggregation network with intermittent running timeouts and boot errors.

**Troubleshooting**

Past a myriad of server side configuration testing (thanks to [George](https://askubuntu.com/users/459561/george) for the support) the intermittent network problem persisted. A compatibility issue was deduced between the builtin Broadcom and the pci Intel nics when bonded in Ubuntu 16.04 lts.

**Hardware Solution**

Two dual Intel pci nics were installed on the 2950 riser pci slots, nvram cleared and the builtin broadcom were disabled from bios. This was done to favor bandwidth i.e. 4 (1Gb) nics instead of the 2 (1Gb) builtin interfaces.

**Server Solution**

There are conflicting bonding configuration suggestions for Ubuntu 16.04 lts and this is what worked for me.

**1**. Ran `ifconfig -a` to get hold of the new interface bios and dev names

```
borgf003@CLD01:~$ ifconfig -a
..........
enp10s0f0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:4a:94:26
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5161 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:361 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:809816 (809.8 KB)  TX bytes:31274 (31.2 KB)
          Interrupt:17 Memory:fdae0000-fdb00000

enp10s0f1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:4a:94:26
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11440 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1963591 (1.9 MB)  TX bytes:20970 (20.9 KB)
          Interrupt:18 Memory:fdaa0000-fdac0000

enp14s0f0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:4a:94:26
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4769 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3294 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:582742 (582.7 KB)  TX bytes:1546925 (1.5 MB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:fd6e0000-fd700000

enp14s0f1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:4a:94:26
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3910 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2548 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:497874 (497.8 KB)  TX bytes:838297 (838.2 KB)
          Interrupt:17 Memory:fd6a0000-fd6c0000
..........
```

**2**. As I had bonding preconfigured before I ran `sudo apt install --reinstall ifenslave`

**3**. Checked if bonding is loaded at boot `sudo nano /etc/modules`

```
loop
lp
bonding
```

NOTE: I remove rtc as it is depreciated in 16.04 lts and I like a clean boot

**4**. Stopped networking in my case I use `sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop`

**5**. Edited the interfaces /etc/network/interfaces with the bond as follows. Note that you need to change the interfaces name with yours, including the ips

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp10s0f0
iface enp10s0f0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# The second network interface
auto enp10s0f1
iface enp10s0f1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# The third network interface
auto enp14s0f0
iface enp14s0f0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# The forth network interface
auto enp14s0f1
iface enp14s0f1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# The bond master network interface
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        network xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        dns-search yourdomain.com
        bond-mode 4
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-slaves all
```

**6**. Reloaded the kernel bond module `sudo modprobe bonding`

**7**. Created a bonding configuration `/etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf` with

```
alias bond0 bonding
options bonding mode=4 miimon=100 lacp_rate=1
```

**8**. Restarted the network, in my case I use `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

**9**. Checked the bond `cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0`

**10**. Reboot to see if all holds up!

Answer (score 0):

First check if **networking** is set to run at boot:

`sudo systemctl status networking`

If it does not say **enabled** on the **Loaded** line, then you have to enable it to start at reboot like so:

`sudo systemctl enable networking`

[image]

Since your bonding these should resolve the matter:

1. install this `sudo apt install ifenslave`
2. edit your `/etc/modules` files: `sudo vi /etc/modules`
3. add these to the file (one on each line)

   - loop
   - lp
   - rtc
   - bonding
4. stop networking:

   - `sudo stop networking`
5. load bonding kernel module:

   - `sudo modprobe bonding`
6. edit your interfaces configuration:

   - **you have done that already**
7. Add this to `vim /etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf`

   `alias bond0 bonding
       options bonding mode=4 miimon=100 lacp_rate=1`
8. start the network again:

   - `sudo systemctl restart networking`
9. check all is well with the bonding interface

   - `cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0`
10. Bring up the bonding interface:

    - `ifup bond0`

Source: [UbuntuBonding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding)

source: [ServerVault](https://serverfault.com/questions/776057/802-3ad-bonding-configuration-file-on-an-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server)

Comment: George, I did reboot and checked if networking is enabled and it is active past boot. I am able to ping most of the internal lan ips but cannot ping outside the gateway. To resolve the issue I would need to restart the networking service via sudo /etc/init.d/networking/restart. What might be the problem?

Comment: please do that and let me know if it works.

Comment: George, I reboot and check if the network is active as you instructed which is past boot, and did enter sudo systemctl enable networking as you guided. Unfortunately as informed in my previous comment, I am able to ping the inner lan but cannot ping outside the gateway unless I do a sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart. I am also noticing that I am getting disconnected over a period of time that exceeds 24 hours. The network seems so unstable. How can I test further to give you better guidance.

Comment: George, please check the Edit 1 as I uploaded an image of the display showing your suggestions and the fact that past them I am still not able to ping outside my gateway until I do sudo /etc/init.d/network restart. Please guide.

Comment: your doing bonding i guess, now did you install this package `ifenslave` ?

Comment: Yes i did install ifenslave as I followed the bonding instructions on UbuntuBonding

Comment: please do an `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` just to be sure some thing isn't off.

Comment: I did a restore with sudo apt install --reinstall ifenslave and checked the entire bonding setup step by step to no avail.

Comment: I will looking for a solution when I get one will post it here.

Comment: George, recalling the initial installation of the server, the NICs were renamed to the conventional eth* would this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Any possibility of reverting them to see if it allows access ?

Comment: I have amended the grub file and removed "net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0" from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX, reconfigured the grub.cfg file, edited the /etc/network/interfaces to reflect the original interfaces name, reboot, etc. but still I cannot get to ping outside the inner lan.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, did you try step 7 in my updated answer ?

Comment: Did that and checked bond0 (see Edit 3)

Comment: George I did a sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf and created the file again. Rebooted twice and the network is now holding up.

Comment: Unbelievable, the network went down again...

Comment: Oh great to hear, what a day with you. All the best!

Comment: check the status using `sudo systemctl status networking`

Comment: Did that under Edit 4

Comment: change the mode to 1, in steps 7.

Comment: But I am on bond 802.3ad = mode 4 would that impact if I change the mode to 1

Comment: it switches between your slaves see [here](http://www.cloudibee.com/network-bonding-modes/), kinda suspecting hardware.

Comment: I am suspecting that too, kinda compatibility issues between 2 Intels with 2 Broadcoms. It worked fine with ESXi but seems to generate issues with Ubuntu's bonding. First thing in the morning, I will remove the bond and compile just one made of the broadcoms which are built in on the main board of the PowerEdge.

Comment: Ok, let me know how it all goes. Best of luck and compliments of the season.

Comment: George as we both suspected the problem was hardware compatibility between the Intels and the Broadcoms. What I did was disabled the built in broadcoms and place two dual 100/1000mbs Intel cards on the dell riser pci slots, thankfully had some in stock and reconfigured the /etc/network/interfaces to reflect the new nic. Checked the bond and reboot the server four times in a row to test for boot up errors and it worked just fine. Will be posting the finds in this post as an answer for others to be guided with. Compliments to you too for the season.

Comment: Sure glad that was finally sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

You are chasing a dead end that way. Your incompatibilities are probably merely settings and race conditions. The **switch** and **nic** particular **settings** and **capabilities** and the **bonding driver** and **kernel settings** all need to be examined to see what's actually wrong.
         It's time to dump all that went before and get down and dirty
                  with **systemd-networkd** itself.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd.service.html#

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt

Comment: the problem was solved via accepted answer. The issue was indeed an incompatibility issue between broadcom and intel nics.