# 16.04 Unable to create Bond

Tags: 16.04, server, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge, network-bonding

I'm trying to set up a specific network configuration on an Ubuntu server 16.04 in order to use KVM.

I need to create three bond, one without bridge, one with a bridge and Vlan.
All bond are in active-backup mode

---

Bond :

```
Bond0 --> br0 --> ip address
Bond1 --> br1 --> 
          Bond1.103 --> br1.103 --> ip address
Bond5 --> ip address
```

---

For the moment, there is only the first bond/bridge which working fine (*bond0*/*br0*).

**Here the configuration :**

```
# The primary network interface
auto ens1f0
iface ens1f0 inet manual
bond-master bond0
bond-primary ens1f0

auto ens1f1
iface ens1f1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

#Bond0
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
        bond_slaves none
        bond-downdelay 0
        bond-updelay 0
        bond-miimon 100
        #bond_mode 1

#br0
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports bond0
        bridge_fd 5
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_maxwait 1
        address 192.15.22.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.15.22.255
        gateway 192.15.22.254
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

The second one (*bond1*/*br1*) seems to be up but I'm unable to raise vlan (*bond1.103*) and bridge (*cloudbr1.103*)

**Here the configuration :**

```
auto enp2s0f0
iface enp2s0f0 inet manual
bond-master bond1
bond-primary enp2s0f0

auto enp2s0f1
iface enp2s0f1 inet manual
bond-master bond1

#bond1
auto bond1
iface bond1 inet manual
        bond-downdelay 0
        bond-updelay 0
        bond-miimon 100
        bond_slaves none

# VLAN 
#vlan103
auto bond1.103
        iface  bond1.103 inet manual
        vlan_raw_device bond1

# BRIDGES 
#br1
auto br1
iface br1 inet manual
    bridge_ports bond1
    bridge_fd 5
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_maxwait 1

#br1.103
auto br1.103
iface br1.103 inet static
        address 192.15.3.218
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.15.3.0
        gateway 192.15.3.254
        bridge_ports bond1.103
        bridge_fd 5
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_maxwait 1
```

And the last one, I made exactly the same config than *bond0* but the bonding is not raised during boot or a network restart...

**Here the configuration :**

```
auto ens2f0
iface ens2f0 inet manual
bond-master bond5
bond-primary ens2f0

auto ens2f1
iface ens2f1 inet manual
bond-master bond5


#bond5
auto bond5
iface bond5 inet static
        address 192.15.5.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.15.5.254
        network 192.15.5.0
        broadcast 192.15.5.255
        bond_slaves none
        bond-downdelay 0
        bond-updelay 0
        bond-miimon 100
        #bond_mode 1
```

**syslog error related to this bond :**

```
Jul  2 11:00:35 KVM08 kernel: [86708.649875] bond5: Removing slave ens2f1
Jul  2 11:00:35 KVM08 kernel: [86708.649927] bond5: Releasing backup interface ens2f1
Jul  2 11:00:35 KVM08 kernel: [86708.649931] bond5: the permanent HWaddr of ens2f1 - 68:b5:99:b5:a4:84 - is still in use by bond5 - set the HWaddr of ens2f1 to a different address to avoid conflicts
Jul  2 11:00:37 KVM08 kernel: [86709.981820] bond5: Removing slave ens2f0
Jul  2 11:00:37 KVM08 kernel: [86709.981876] bond5: Releasing active interface ens2f0
Jul  2 11:00:37 KVM08 kernel: [86710.004204] bonding: bond5 is being deleted...
Jul  2 11:00:37 KVM08 kernel: [86710.005675] bond5 (unregistering): Released all slaves
Jul  2 11:00:37 KVM08 systemd[1]: Stopping ifup for bond5...
Jul  2 11:00:37 KVM08 ifdown[6310]: /sbin/ifdown: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.bond5
Jul  2 11:00:37 KVM08 ifdown[6310]: /sbin/ifdown: interface bond5 not configured
Jul  2 11:00:37 KVM08 systemd[1]: Stopped ifup for bond5.
```

I already followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858824/ubuntu-16-04-lts-network-does-not-start-on-boot-bonding) thread.

So if somone may take a look to my config and check if there are some errors...

Comment: Bond5 is now good, it was a problem from the "other-side"

Comment: and vlan as well, ubuntu don't like dot in the interface name.
br1.103 --> br103